# Is "git-svn clone" on linux the same as "git svn clone" on the mac?

Tags: macos, git, git-svn

Is "git-svn clone" on linux the same as "git svn clone" on the mac?

On Linux I know I can do the following command to clone a svn repo

```
git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
```

but on my MAC I can't find git-svn so will the following command work

```
git svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
```

Comment: The two commands that you supplied as examples are identical.  FYI, the dashed forms such as `git-svn` have been deprecated for some time.  Unless you're using a really old version of git you should be using `git svn` even on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `git-svn` and `git svn` are equivalent (just like e.g. `git-commit` and `git commit` and others).